# Approximate regular expressions error counting behavior

Tags: python, regex

I am using the [regex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to work with approximate regular expressions in Python. I do not understand the behavior I see when errors are counted in matches.

If I use the following regular expression with errors allowed:

```
>>> rex = '(HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES){e}'
```

I get exactly the behavior I expect, where a match is found with 20 errors. The 20 errors are due to the 20 lowercase letters:

```
>>> regex.match(rex, 'House of Representatives')

<regex.Match object; span=(0, 24), match='House of Representatives', fuzzy_counts=(20, 0, 0)>
```

---

When I attempt to something similar with added complexity, I get a result that makes no sense to me.

I am attempting to match strings that look like: "HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES\nWEDNESDAY, JANUARY 23, 1939\n".

```
>>> rex = '(HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES\n[A-Z]{3,6}DAY, [A-Z]{3,11} [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}\n){e}'
```

When I attempt to use this, I get an error number that I cannot understand.

```
>>> h1 = 'HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES\nWEDNESDAY, JANUARY 4, 1939\n'
>>> regex.match(rex, h1)
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 52), match='HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES\nWEDNESDAY, JANUARY 4, 1939\n', fuzzy_counts=(7, 0, 2)>
```

I get a match 9 fuzzy errors when I expect 0. What gives?

Note: When I use the BESTMATCH flag, I get 8 errors.

Comment: Why you count on errors?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work to match what you are looking for:

```
(HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES)\\n[A-Z]{3,6}DAY,\s[A-Z]{3,11}\s[0-9]{1,2},\s[0-9]{4}\\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/sQ5hQ2/3

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: The regex doesn't answer your question or are you not looking for a regex?

Comment: The question I asked is about the regex package and how errors are counted with approximate matching.